# truckRestrictionPenalty=soft in here maps android sdk

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I'm doing a new feature of sending routes for trucks calculating in here rest api to android app (works with here maps android sdk). In here rest api we are using `truckRestrictionPenalty=soft` in route calculate request. When I'll send this same waypoints to mobile app and calculate route with here maps android sdk I get error: GRAPH_DISCONNECTED

I tried to use the DynamicPenalty in CoreRouter but it didn't help:

```
coreRouter.dynamicPenalty = DynamicPenalty().apply { 
        trafficPenaltyMode = Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.DISABLED
}
```

It is possible to set somethink like `truckRestrictionPenalty=soft` in here maps android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the traffic penalty mode to DISABLED which is why you are getting GRAPH_DISCONNECTED that signifies no route found(https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RoutingError.html).

It is possible that route is not considered for completely violating restrictions. Have you tried with OPTIMAL mode.

DynamicPenalty dp = new DynamicPenalty();
dp.setTrafficPenaltyMode(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.OPTIMAL);

CoreRouter cr = new CoreRouter();
cr.setDynamicPenalty(dp);